# Getting AsyncTask result data from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have AsyncTask class called **LoadXMLData**, and as you can see I parse XML data in **doInBackground()** method.

```
public class LoadXMLData extends AsyncTask<String, RSSFeed, RSSFeed>{

public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;


private Context context;
RSSFeed feed;



public LoadXMLData(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Molimo Vas, sačekajte. Podaci se učitavaju.");
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    mProgressDialog.show();
    Log.d("OVDE SAM:", "onPreExecute()");
}

@Override
protected RSSFeed doInBackground(String... urls) {
    // Obtain feed
    DOMParser myParser = new DOMParser();
    feed = myParser.parseXml(urls[0]);
    Log.d("OVDE SAM:", "PARSIRAM XML");
    return feed;
}



@Override
protected void onPostExecute(RSSFeed result) {
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();

    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

}

And I have few fragments, where I need to get data from that AsyncTask. How I could do that?

Here is the code of an fragment called **NajnovijeFragment**.

```
public class NajnovijeFragment extends Fragment{

GridView lv;
RSSFeed feed;
CustomListAdapter adapter;
private String RSSFEEDURL = "http://balkanandroid.com/feed/";

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_najnovije, container,
            false);     


    lv = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.GridView1);

    // Set an Adapter to the ListView
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter();
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Set on item click listener to the ListView
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // actions to be performed when a list item clicked
            int pos = arg2;

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("feed", feed);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            intent.putExtra("pos", pos);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public CustomListAdapter() {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Set the total list item count
        return feed.getItemCount();
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Inflate the item layout and set the views
        View listItem = convertView;
        int pos = position;
        if (listItem == null) {
            listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        // Initialize the views in the layout
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.thumb);
        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView tvDate = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);

        // Set the views in the layout
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(feed.getItem(pos).getImage(), iv);
        tvTitle.setText(feed.getItem(pos).getTitle());
        tvDate.setText(feed.getItem(pos).getDate());

        return listItem;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to get data from an ASyncTask is by implementing a callback.

Create an Interface:

```
public interface OnXMLLoadFinishedListener {
  public void onXMLDataReady(RSSFeed results);
}
```

In you LoadXMLData:

```
private OnXMLLoadFinishedListener listener;

public void setOnXMLLoadFinishedListener(OnXMLLoadFinishedListener listener){
  this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(RSSFeed result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    listener.onXMLDataReady(RSSFeed results);
}
```

In your Fragment:

```
public class NajnovijeFragment extends Fragment implements OnXMLLoadFinishedListener{
```

and override onXMLDataReady:

```
@override
public void onXMLDataReady(RSSFeed results){
   //display your data.
}
```

Make sure that when you create your AsyncTask instance you set the listener otherwise this will not work:

```
LoadXMLData xmlLoader = new LoadXMLData();
xmlLoader.setOnXMLLoadFinishedListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask is a Class that is very related to the UI, if you need to update the UI with this XML parsing you should take this consideration:

- Make the asynctask an inner class in your fragment or
- Pass the fragment to your asynctask
- Update the fragment's view in onPostExecute()

In any case you should check if your activity is null, if so... avoid updating views, something like that:

```
onPostExecute(Object xml) {
   if(getActivity != null) {
      // update Views like...
      textViewLabel.setText(parsedXml.getTitle);
   }
}
```

I would suggest you to use SafeAsyncTask, which is a java class from the Roboguice Project, only one file, and it is related to java.util.concurrent.Callable, just copy and paste the source:

[SafeAsyncTask.java](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/blob/master/roboguice/src/main/java/roboguice/util/SafeAsyncTask.java?source=cc)

[How to use it!](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/Working-with-RoboAsyncTask)

Comment: I tried to use AsyncTask as inner class of fragment class, but I stil can get result of AsyncTask in my case RSSFeed feed, because I get nullpointer exception on feed.getItemCount(); because I get null on RSSFeed feed.

Comment: So the problem is related to the XML parser, right? Try with "Simple" is an xml parser, really good. Check:

http://simple.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Nope, everything is fine with XML parser, problem is just that I can get result of AsyncTask in fragment class.

Comment: That is because on the onPostExecute method is empty, I mean... you are not doing anything with the fragment.

Comment: How I can fix that? Can you post some code that wowrk that, and I will acpet your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your AsyncTask already knows context, so you could call back into your activity (called ActivityMain for illustrative purposes) in onPostExecute. e.g.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
 super.onPostExecute(result);
 ((ActivityMain) context).loadCompleteHandler(param1,param2,...)
}
```

It's then up to you how you want to implement loadCompleteHandler in your activity. Now your activity might not exist, so you must be careful to cancel the AsyncTask when the activity is removed. Fragments belonging to an activity can also access the activity.

Comment: Implement loadCompleteHandler to store the result somewhere in the activity and have your fragments pick it up from there.

Comment: Time is limited atm. Please define what format data you are trying to make available to your fragments.

Comment: I have class RSSFeed, with all getters and setters. So I would need to  acces content of RSSFeed in my fragments class. This code I use for parsing: RSSFeed feed;  DOMParser myParser = new DOMParser();
    feed = myParser.parseXml(urls[0]); So I need content of that "feed" in my fragment class.